# Need touch tutorial

Tags: android, touch, new-operator

I am new to android so please if I sound stupid, do not reply.

Hello,
I have tried searching all over the net for a good tutorial that would help me understand how android takes the touch events and reacts accordingly. But I have not been successful. If anyone knows a good tutorial that could help me, please post it here. It would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This tutorial is a bit long, but it takes you through start-to-finish creating a simple app that handles touch events.  I liked it and hope it helps:

http://www.kellbot.com/2009/06/android-hello-circle/

Answer (score 2):

To make it simple...

There is an hierarchy of views that Android maintains and the events are handled accordingly.
Every View in the hierarchy gets the event, **but only if the parent event has not consume it**. Meaning - if you have a parent view that handles onTouchEvent() and returns **true** every time, the child never receives the event.

That should explain the main behaviour, but feel free to post some additional questions :)

Answer (score 2):

This tut gives a quick overview on how Android handles touch events. Plus ScaleGestureDetector class is explained.Hope it helps:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidTouch/article.html